# Auto layout constraints not behaving correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

So I have a pretty simple layout for a view that I have created, basically what i want it to look like after I'm done with adding constraints is as follows,

[image]

However, what I end up with is something else, and Im not sure why this behavior is happening.

[image]

So just a quick rundown of what I did in an attempt to achieve the layouts I wanted.

1. Center the X position of the **"/"** label
2. Set the the **indexLabel** that can be seen towards the left that says "1"
3. Constraint the **"reps"** label to the left of **"/"** label
4. Finally constraint the **"reps field"** to the right of **indexLabel** and left of **"reps" label**

---

```
private func setupDividerLabelLayout() {
    addSubview(dividerLabel)

    dividerLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    dividerLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
}

private func setupIndexLabelBackgroundLayout() {
    addSubview(indexLabelBackground)

    indexLabelBackground.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    indexLabelBackground.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    indexLabelBackground.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true
    indexLabelBackground.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true

}

private func setupRepsLabelLayout() {
    addSubview(repsLabel)

    repsLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dividerLabel.leftAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    repsLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}

private func setupRepsFieldLayout() {
    addSubview(repsField)

    repsField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: repsLabel.leftAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    repsField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    repsField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: indexLabelBackground.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: when you share an image in your question, don't remove the last lines from the question. (like:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/......jpg)

Comment: yea just noticed that edited

Comment: use stack view rather than messing up with auto layout constraints manually

Comment: could you give an example? I don't see how it is possible to achieve the layout that I want with a stack view since I cant center items in a stack view such as my divider label

Answer (score 0):

In order let you anchors work you should add `_ViewName_.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`. 
 so the code becomes as follows
**Code to Use**

```
private func setupDividerLabelLayout() {
    addSubview(dividerLabel)

    dividerLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    dividerLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    dividerLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}

private func setupIndexLabelBackgroundLayout() {
    addSubview(indexLabelBackground)

    indexLabelBackground.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    indexLabelBackground.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    indexLabelBackground.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true
    indexLabelBackground.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true
    indexLabelBackground.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

}

private func setupRepsLabelLayout() {
    addSubview(repsLabel)

    repsLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dividerLabel.leftAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    repsLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    repsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

}

private func setupRepsFieldLayout() {
    addSubview(repsField)

    repsField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: repsLabel.leftAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    repsField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    repsField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
    indexLabelBackground.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    repsField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    indexLabelBackground.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

}
```

Comment: That is already done, it was just omitted, sorry about the confusion